# maximum i-j , so that A[i]>=A[j]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, int

Let us assume that we have an array A of positive integers. Our task is to find the maximum posible i-j , i>j  that holds the following property :  A[i]>=A[j].

To give an example , if

```
A[0]=78
A[1]=88
A[2]=64
A[3]=94
A[4]=17
A[5]=91
A[6]=57
A[7]=69
A[8]=38
A[9]=62
A[10]=13
A[11]=17
A[12]=35
A[13]=15
A[14]=20
A[15]=15
```

then the answer is 10 , because for i=14 and j=4 , A[i]>A[j] .

Which is the most suitable algorithm for the task?

So far , I have considered the following algorithm :
I apply mergesort . I use a variable max to store the final answer. Whenever A[i] and A[j] are NOT swapped , I check if i-j> max  . If so , I update max.
time complexity : O(nlogn).

Is there a better algorithm?

Comment: What do you mean by better? Does it mean faster in terms of time or space complexity? Does it mean an algorithm which is simpler to implement?

Comment: By "better" I mean better time complexity.

Comment: Why isn't the answer i=5 (91) and j=4 (17) since the A[i] (91) >= A[j] (17) and i > j?. Do you need the maximum possible i-j in terms of indexes or values?

Comment: If we choose i=5 and j=4 , it is true that A[i] > A[j] . However , we would have 5-4=1 as an answer . If we choose i=14 and j=4 , it is also true that A[i] > A[j] . In this case , we have 14-4=10 .  We need to find the maximum i-j , so we choose i=14 and j=4 and the answer is 10.

Comment: @Caner: Why did you delete your answer? It was correct (at least after my edits).

Comment: @user3697730 I'm not sure your algorithm is correct or is it really O(nlogn). What do you mean by ` Whenever A[i] and A[j] are NOT swapped `?

Comment: The merge part of mergesort will be something like this :  void merging(int low, int mid, int high) {
   int l1, l2, i;

   for(l1 = low, l2 = mid + 1, i = low; l1 <= mid && l2 <= high; i++) {
      if(a[l1] <= a[l2])
         b[i] = a[l1++];
      else
         b[i] = a[l2++];
   }
   
   while(l1 <= mid)    
      b[i++] = a[l1++];

   while(l2 <= high)   
      b[i++] = a[l2++];

   for(i = low; i <= high; i++)
      a[i] = b[i];
}              If a[l1]<= a[l2] , then  that's what I meant by "NOT swapped" . I mean than A[i] >= A[j] initially . I didn't explain it well...

Comment: Whenever an element with smaller index is smaller than an element with a larger index during the merge part of mergesort, it means that initially  A[i]>=A[j]  with i>j .

Comment: @user3697730: That's not going to work. Even if you keep information about the original locations of elements (so you can actually compute i-j values), you'll likely never look at the i and j you need to look at at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

We can do this in O(N) for a length-N array.

For an `i` and `j` giving us the maximum `i-j`, we must have `A[i]` greater than all subsequent elements and `A[j]` less than all previous elements. Otherwise, we could pick a later `A[i]`, or an earlier `A[j]`, and get a greater `i-j`.

Find all elements of `A` greater than all subsequent elements, and all elements of `A` less than all previous elements:

```
j_candidates = [0]
for j in range(1, N):
    if A[j] < A[j_candidates[-1]]:
        j_candidates.append(j)

i_candidates = [N-1]
for i in reversed(range(N-1)):
    if A[i] > A[i_candidates[-1]]:
        i_candidates.append(i)
i_candidates.reverse()
```

Then for each `j` candidate, find the best corresponding `i` candidate, *starting the search from the previous `j` candidate's best `i` candidate*.

```
best_distance = 0
i_candidate_index = 0
for j in j_candidates:
    while (i_candidate_index + 1 < len(i_candidates)
           and A[j] <= A[i_candidates[i_candidate_index+1]]):
        i_candidate_index += 1
    best_distance = max(best_distance, i_candidates[i_candidate_index] - j)
```

Comment: How is this O(n)? The second part is O(n^2), no? What am I missing?

Comment: @Caner: The second part is O(N). The inner loop doesn't go over the whole `i_candidates` list every time; over the course of the whole outer loop, the inner loop only performs O(len(i_candidates)+len(j_candidates)) iterations.

Comment: Yes, which is O(n), that makes this algorithm  O(n^2)

Comment: @Caner: It performs O(n) iterations *across the entire execution of the outer loop*, not O(n) iterations on every iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Consider this case: A[0]=N, A[1]=N-1,A[2]=N-2. Both i_candidate and j_candidate arrays will have N members.

Comment: @Caner: Still O(N). You probably have a wrong mental model of how asymptotic complexity works. [Have some timings.](http://ideone.com/yAq72M)

Comment: Actually turns out my algorithm is also O(n)

Comment: @Caner: Yours isn't; you're getting fooled by the fact that it almost always exits early with random input. With [worst-case input](http://ideone.com/iUDJUd), the O(N^2) behavior becomes apparent. (My timings don't prove that my solution is O(N) either - timings can't really prove that.)

Comment: Right, yours scales linearly and mine doesn't with worst case input